# Solving sub-triangles for Barycentric Interpolation (Triangle Geometry)

Tags: geometry, interpolation

I'm trying to solve this triangle, so I can implement a barycentric interpolation, but I'm having trouble solving everything. I have all the base values for each of triangular sections and with a simple Euclidean distance, I also have the distances from the corner nodes to the particle in question (red dot within the triangle).

It just turned out that in this case I had the right triangle with the pink subtriangle, but I think that's just happenstance and won't occur every time...in which case I'd need a concrete method for finding the height of the sub-triangles.

I could very well be staring at the answer or have already read it, and I apologize if this is rudimentary.

Thank you very much for your help!

Reference Article:

http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps160/Fall10/resources/barycentricInterpolation.pdf

If anyone has a better suggestion for barycentric interpolation, and the will to explain it,  I'd be greatly appreciative!

Best regards,

P

[image: Solving sub-triangles for barycentric interpolation]

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly you are asking. Are you looking for a result for this single depicted triangle, or is that an example and you need a general method? What exactly are your inputs? Desired output would be [barycentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system), possibly scaled so their sum equals one, right?

Comment: I am trying to solve the areas for the triangles in order to complete a barycentric linear interpolation. As the posted link suggests you can do so by area. I can't seem to figure the height values for the sub-triangles, thus making it hard to complete the area. I didn't know if that route would prove impossible or I'm just (likely) not doing something geometrically possible with the triangles.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question about what the inputs are. And when answering a comment from a user, you should include `@` followed by his name (e.g. `@MvG`) so that the user will get [notified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/188688) of the fact that you are talking to him. This is particularly important if there were comments from more than one user.

Comment: @MvG

My question was purely asking if there was a way to solve a triangle such as the orange or blue triangles, in the event you're not given the height or angles of the triangle like that.

The pink triangle was only able to be solved because it was a right triangle, I wanted to know, that in the event that you're not given the right triangle, and only given the outside (major triangle) distances, and the distances from each of the three triangular corners to the point in question IF there was anyway to solve the areas of the sub-triangles (orange, blue, pink).

Comment: @MvG in short,all that is known is the sides of the original triangle, and the distances from each corner of the triangle to any point that falls within the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment above clarified that you are essentially asking for a way to compute the area $T$ of a triangle, given the lengths of all three edges, i.e. $a,b,c$. This is best done using [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Using_Heron.27s_formula):

$$T=\tfrac14\sqrt{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}$$

You can do so for every one of the three triangles. For barycentric coordinates, only the ratio between areas matters, so you may as well drop this factor $\frac14$.